# How to Store values from Javascript Calculator to MySQL Database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a JavaScript Calculator which is getting values from user but there is no html input fields for these and I want to store the values from this to the MySQL database. But I think without using PHP, I cannot do this. Is there any way to put these values to MySQL database directly or I can get access of these variables in PHP. Kindly suggest some solution for this.

```
    var budget_calculator = (function($){
    //Set the default incomes and outgoings here
    var defaultsObj = {
        'income':{
            1:{name:"Maintenance Loan",freq:12,value:0},
            2:{name:"Scholarships",freq:12,value:0},
            3:{name:"Work Income",freq:12,value:0},
            4:{name:"Parental Support",freq:12,value:0},
                        5:{name:"Other",freq:12,value:0},
        },'outgoings':{
            1:{name:"Rent",freq:12,value:0},
            2:{name:"Bills",freq:12,value:0},
            3:{name:"Groceries",freq:12,value:0},
            4:{name:"Commuting",freq:12,value:0},
            5:{name:"Phone",freq:12,value:0},
            6:{name:"Books",freq:12,value:0},
            7:{name:"Stationary",freq:12,value:0},
            8:{name:"Going Out",freq:12,value:0},
            9:{name:"Hobbies",freq:12,value:0},
            10:{name:"Gym",freq:12,value:0},
            11:{name:"Other",freq:12,value:0}
        }
    };


    //Functions to store and retrieve objects from localstorage
    function ls_store(name,o){
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(o));
    };
    function ls_read(name){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
    };
    //Format a currency string
    function format_currency(num) {
        var p = num.toFixed(0).split(".");
        return "£" + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
            return  num + (i && !(i % 3) && !(num=='-') ? "," : "") + acc;
        }, "");
    }

    function set_defaults(){
        ls_store('bc_expenses',defaultsObj);
        expensesObj = ls_read('bc_expenses');
    }
    //If our localstroage items are empty let's store the defaults
    if(ls_read('bc_expenses')==null){
        set_defaults();
    }
    var expensesObj = ls_read('bc_expenses');
    //Reset the localstorage if the clear link is clicked
    $('.reset-localstorage').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        set_defaults();
        display_tables();
    });
    //Set our frequencies object
    var frequenciesObj = {52:"Weekly", 26:"Fortnightly", 12:"Monthly", 4:"Quarterly", 1:"Annually"};
    function display_percents(element_class, value, percent){
        $('#totals '+element_class+' > h3 > span').html(format_currency(value));
        $('#totals '+element_class+' .progress-bar').html('<span class="percent">' + percent.toFixed(2)+'%</span>')
        if(percent<0){
            $('#totals '+element_class+' .progress-bar').css('width',(percent*-1)+'%').addClass('progress-bar-danger');
        }else{
            $('#totals '+element_class+' .progress-bar').css('width',percent+'%').removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        }
    }
    function calc_totals(){
        var income_total = 0;
        var outgoings_total = 0;
        for(var i in expensesObj['income']){
            var e = expensesObj['income'][i];
            //income_total = income_total+e.value * e.freq;
            income_total = income_total+e.value * e.freq ;
        }
        for(var i in expensesObj['outgoings']){
            var e = expensesObj['outgoings'][i];
            outgoings_total = outgoings_total+e.value * e.freq;
        }
        var outgoings_percent = (outgoings_total/income_total)*100;
        var income_percent = 100-outgoings_percent;
        var savings_total = parseInt(income_total - outgoings_total,10);
        var savings_percentage = (savings_total/income_total)*100;
        display_percents('.total-income', income_total, income_percent);if(isNaN(income_percent)){display_percents('.total-income', 0, 0)}
        display_percents('.total-outgoings', outgoings_total, outgoings_percent);if(isNaN(outgoings_percent)){display_percents('.total-outgoings', 0, 0)}
        display_percents('.total-savings', savings_total, savings_percentage);if(isNaN(savings_percentage)){display_percents('.total-savings', 0, 0)}
    }
    //Function to calculate the incomes or outgoings
    function calc_costs(){
        for(var type in expensesObj){
            var total = 0;
            $('.budget-calculator #'+type+' tbody tr').each(function() {
                var amount = $(this).find('.amount').val();
                var freq = $(this).find('.freq').val();
                var single_total = amount*freq;
                var row_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                if(!isNaN(single_total)){
                    total = total + single_total;
                    $('#'+type+' tbody tr[data-id="'+row_id+'"]').find('.single-total').html(''+format_currency(single_total));
                    $('#'+type+' tfoot .total').html('Total yearly '+type+': '+format_currency(total));
                    expensesObj[type][row_id].value=amount;
                    expensesObj[type][row_id].freq=freq;
                    ls_store('bc_expenses',expensesObj)
                }
            });
        }
        calc_totals();
    }
    //Display the incomes/outgoings objects as a table
    function display_tables(){
        for(var type in expensesObj){
            var d = '';
            for(var i in expensesObj[type]){
                d+='<tr data-id="'+i+'" data-type="'+type+'">'+
                '<td>'+expensesObj[type][i].name+':</td>'+
                '<td><select class="freq">';
                for(var f in frequenciesObj){
                    var selected = '';
                    if(expensesObj[type][i].freq == f){selected = ' selected';}
                    d+='<option value="'+f+'" '+selected+'>'+frequenciesObj[f]+'</option>';
                }
                d+='</select></td>'+
                '<td><input class="amount" type="text" maxlength="8" value="'+expensesObj[type][i].value+'"/></td>'+
                '<td><span class="single-total">$0</span></td>'+
                '<td><span class="remove-row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></span></td>'+
                '</tr>';
            }
            $('.budget-calculator #'+type+' tbody').html(d);
        }
        calc_costs();
    }
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })
    //text value get's changed
    $('.budget-calculator').on('keyup','tbody .amount',function(e) {
        var type= $(this).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id')
        calc_costs()
    });
    //Frequency gets changed
    $('.budget-calculator').on('change','tbody .freq',function(e) {
        var type= $(this).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id')
        calc_costs()
    });
    //Add a row button get's clicked - launch the bootstrap modal
    $('.budget-calculator').on('click','.add-row',function(e) {
        var type= $(this).attr('data-type');
        $('#budget-calculator-add-row .btn-add-row').attr('data-type',type)
        $('#budget-calculator-add-row label').text('Enter name for '+type)
        $('#budget-calculator-add-row').modal();
    });
    //Add a new row
    $('#budget-calculator-add-row .btn-add-row').click(function(e) {
        var val = $('#add-row-name').val();
        var type= $(this).attr('data-type');
       if(val.length>0){
           //Lets add the row
           for(var i in expensesObj[type]){
               var new_index = parseInt(i,10)+1;
           }
           expensesObj[type][new_index] = {name:val,freq:12,value:0}
           ls_store('bc_expenses',expensesObj);//Store the object
           display_tables();
           calc_costs();
           $('#add-row-name').val('')
           $('#budget-calculator-add-row').modal('hide');
        }else{
            console.info('No value Entered so will not save!');
        }
    });
    //Remove a row
    $('.budget-calculator').on('click','.remove-row',function(e) {
        var type= $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-type');
        var id= $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
        delete expensesObj[type][id];
        ls_store('bc_expenses',expensesObj);//Store the object
        display_tables();
        calc_costs();
    })
    //Display the objects as HTML in the forms
    display_tables()
})(jQuery);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Financhester</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Budget Calculator CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="budget-calculator.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
<h1>Financhester</h1>
<h4>Student-Friendly Budgeting Tool</h4>
</div> <!-- endHeader -->

<div class="topnav">
 <a class = "active" href="index.html">Home</a><a href="AmeliaPage/advice page/advice-recommended-apps.html">Deals & Money Advice</a><a href="about.html">About</a>
</div><!-- topNav -->


<div class = "wrapper">
<br>
<h4>How to use Financhester:
<ol>
<li>Enter your income, loans and sholarships/bursaries where applicable.</li>
<li>Enter your estimated expenses.</li>
<li>See your balance down below!</li></h4>
</ol>

<br>

<div class="clear_float">
</div>



<!-- #############  BEGIN Budget Calculator HTML #############  -->
<div class="budget-calculator">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#income" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INCOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#outgoings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">EXPENSES</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="income">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Income Type</th>
                    <th>Frequency</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Annual Amount</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody></tbody>
           <tfoot>
            <tr><td colspan="100"><span class="btn btn-md btn-primary add-row" data-type="income"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> add another source of income</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="100"><span class="total">Total: £0</span></td></tr>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div><!-- tab-pane -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="outgoings">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Expenses Type</th>
                    <th>Frequency</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Annual Amount</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody></tbody>
           <tfoot>
            <tr><td colspan="100"><span class="btn btn-md btn-primary add-row" data-type="outgoings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> add another type of expenses</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="100"><span class="total">Total: £0</span></td></tr>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div><!-- tab-pane -->
      <div class="" id="totals">
        <div class="totals total-income">
        <h2>Your balance</h2>
            <h3>Annual Income: <span>£0</span></h3>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totals total-outgoings">
            <h3>Annual Expenses: <span>£0</span></h3>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totals total-savings">
            <h3>Annual Balance: <span>£0</span></h3>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- tab-pane -->
    </div><!-- tab-content -->
    <!-- bootstrap modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="budget-calculator-add-row">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add row</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="add-row-name">Type of Expenses</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-row-name" placeholder="">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-row" data-type="">Add Row</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>  <!-- .budget-calculator -->
<!-- #############  END Budget Calculator HTML #############  -->

</div><!-- wrapper -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Budget Calculator JS -->
<script src="budget-calculator.js">
</script>

<div class="footer">
<br>
<a href="privacy.html">Privacy policy</a> <a href="terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
<br>
<br>
<p>© 2018 Z1 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>

</div><!-- ###### footer ######  -->



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This is far from being a minimal example. Can you make a version that demonstrates what you are doing, but with less code?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code here. Without going through everything, here is a pretty basic example of insert the calculator value into a database using PHP, MySQL, jQuery, and AJAX.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = ?? // the return value from the calculator
$.ajax({
    data: {value: value},
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://example.com/insert.php",
    success: function(data){
         alert('Successfully saved into database.');
    }
});
</script>

// insert.php:
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (:value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $_POST['value']);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```